# Combine loops to improve runtime?

Tags: arrays, optimization, runtime

I'm curious what the cost of visiting each item in an array is to runtime.  Suppose I have the code,

```
  For( each item in an array)
     'do thing1
   Next item in array

   For( each item in same array)
        'do thing2
    Next item in array
```

Would there be a significant runtime improvement to write it as,

```
  For( each item in an array)
     'do thing1
     'do thing2
   Next item in array
```

I have a bunch of code that uses the first approach and I'm wondering if it would be worthwhile to try and combine some things.  I know the second approach is easier to read, but I'm wondering if runtime is effected.  I know you can access stuff in arrays in constant time, but does accessing something twice, take twice as long?

I'm coding in VBA, if that makes a difference. Would the answer to this question vary depending on what language you were using?  Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

It's iterating over the entire array twice using the first approach, only once using the second approach.  In my opinion, the second way is actually cleaner, and will probably improve runtime as it's not going back to the start of the list and looping through each item a second time.

EDIT:
this wouldn't really be different from one language to another, usually it's best to keep your looping limited to as few iterations as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously  for an array of N elements, Example 1 requires Nx2 reads, Example 2 only N reads.
If your 'do thing' uses each item, the combined code is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

The second example of the two loops combined into one will run faster than the two loops seperately. However, both examples are in the same time efficiency class of O(n) because they only differ by a constant. If you need more help on this subject take a quick look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency) or do a search for algorithm time efficiency, there are some good articles out there that should help you get a good understanding of this.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of maintainability, only you can tell which makes more sense.

If your "do thing" does very little, and if when you take samples, you find the program counter in this code > 10% of the time, then it matters in terms of performance.
Otherwise, it doesn't.

If it does, then in my experience the first option can give better performance, because the compiler is more likely to be able to keep things in registers from one iteration to the next, not having to save and reload them between "thing1" and "thing2".

Also in this case, unrolling will help. Compilers *might* be able to do the unrolling, but personally I don't care for "might".